# Can I just shove all my CSS through an online prefixer?

Tags: css, autoprefixer

Basically, I have finished the CSS for a site at work, but I've never used a prefixer before.

Can I just stick the whole lot (about 900 lines) through an online prefixer E.G. https://autoprefixer.github.io/ ?

Or will this cause issues?

Would I be better using something built into VS Code or using some sort of processor?

Thanks.

P.S. I did look for another question/answer similar to this, but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: It seems google themselves trust on that tool so why don't you?

Comment: No reason, I was just wondering if there is any benefit/drawback to using an online pre-fixer as opposed to some sort of processor/editor plugin. My googling wasn't particularly fruitful in finding an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on chrome and have compleated your project that is totally fine. You can use the auto prefixer without any hesitation. You just need to copy and paste the code then you need to copy the auto prefixed code and paste in your code editor. In rare cases, some of your properties may not work in the other browsers (as I said very rare properties) but that will not affect your existing code I can guarantee that.

Just go through this to know about the existing and deprecated CSS properties.
[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/)